# Are "работа" and "раб" related?

Tags: этимология

From this [Hacker News discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=39081861), I learned that the Czech word "robota" means "forced labor" and has mostly negative connotations. In Polish, which is a closely related Slavic language, it is a rather generic and neutral term for "work". To my knowledge, this is also true in modern Russian. However, considering that the word for "slave" is "раб", I am curious about how these two are related and whether "работа" used to specifically mean forced or slave work in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am curious about how these two are related

*Работа* and *раб* are closely related, both originating from Proto-Slavic **orbъ* "orphan, slave". They are also distant cognates to English "orphan" and (according to some sources) to German *Arbeit* "work".

> whether "работа" used to specifically mean forced or slave work in the past.

Yes, it did (in Old Russian). More specifically, it meant "slavery":

> - и яко взѧ городъ и пожьже и старѣишины же города ижьже и прочая люди ѡвѣхъ изби а другия работѣ преда муже своимъ а прокъ ѡстави ихъ платити дань // *[Повесть временных лет по Ипатьевскому списку (1110-е)]*
>
>   "As she (*Princess Olga*) took the city, she burned it, and burned its eldermen, and killed some of its people, and others consigned to slavery unto her men, and still others made pay tribute"
> - … ѡбрѣтше тѧ проводника яко моисѣа новыи сии изр҃ль изводѧщаго из работы немилосьрдья и ѿ мрака скѹпости. // [Киевская летопись (1119—1199)]
>
>   "(Those who) found a leader in you, like Moses, leading this new Israel away from slavery, cruelty, and the darkness of squalor"

It was used in the sense of "non-forced labor" as well from time to time, but that was a metaphorical, non-primary meaning until well into the late medieval.

Comment: Interesting! So, "robot" is not only "slave", but also "orphan". I'm wondering if Čapek was aware of that...

Comment: @gog: just to clarify, the meaning of "orphan" is reconstructed from other PIE branches and semantic parallels (cf. _otrok_ "slave" in West Slavic). It isn't directly attested in any Slavic languages, not that I'm aware.